# ffmpeg extract multiple frames from single input

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to dynamically extract multiple different frames from single video input. So the command I'm calling looking like this

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -hide_banner -t 13.269541 -y -ss 0 -i "input-s3-url" -ss 13.269541 -i "same-input-s3-url" -map 0:v -vframes 1 /tmp/ca4cd7a3159743938c5362c171ea2cae.0.png -map 1:v -vframes 1 /tmp/ca4cd7a3159743938c5362c171ea2cae.13.269541.png
```

It works and everything is good, until I deploy it to lambda. Even though I'm using 10gb of RAM it still failing with error. Locally it works like a charm but not on lambda. I'm not sure what the problem here but i'm regularly (not always) getting SIGSEGV

[image]

Double-checked memory usage and it's doesn't look like a reason

[image]

I'm think maybe it's because it's making requests for each input, at least that's what I saw in debug mode, but still have no idea what's the problem here, would appreciate any suggestions/optimizations/help.
Thanks